# Add existing marker to map

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an app in which I manually added some `Markers` to a `google map`. Then I saved the Markers to local storage. Now I want to re-run the app, load the set of markers and place them on the (now empty) map. I had assumed that there would be a method something like:

`googleMap.addMarker(marker_I_loaded_from_memory)`, but I can't find it. Alternatively I thought there may be something like `marker_I_loaded_from_memory.AddMyselfToMap()`, but I can't find that either. Does either exist?

**Edit:** I am using maps API v 2

Comment: I don't know if I understood clearly but suggestion would be:

googleMap.addMarker accepts MarkerOptions. Either you saved the object MarkerOptions and it just loads up again or you save the coordinates of that marker instead, and then just resume with googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions(..));

Comment: What precisely have you saved in LocalStorage?

Comment: @Andre Dion: I made a class which included assorted data associated with a marker as well as the Marker itself. I then saved the entire class.

Comment: @Mick `localStorage` will only store string values, so are your first serializing your object? Please include the actual value of your `localStorage` store in your question.

Comment: I did serialise, but however its saved/loaded... I still have the question of how to get the marker on the map... if it can't be done then my loading/saving mechanism is irrelevant.

Comment: @Mick It's completely relevant, but you seem to be doing your best to avoid help. Best of luck.

Comment: I'm not confident that I have correctly stored/re-created my marker so I didn't want to share that code - but the question is not about how to save a Marker class (if I've done that bit wrong I'll fix it myself), its about *assuming you have correctly got a Marker*, THEN how do you attach it to the map. I haven't got fully debugged code for load/save written yet.

Comment: Are you using [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/index)?

Comment: Yes, version 2 - I'll put it in the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot serialize `Marker` objects. They are connected with current view.

I suggest storing the relevant data in local DB. A table with latitude, longitude, title, etc. will do.

When recreating such `Marker`s, use `GoogleMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions)`, where `MarkerOptions` is constructed from the data in DB.

Comment: `map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat,long)).title(title).snippet(snippet).icon(icon));` It's almost all you need I think.